# Why does TextMateRules not change my punctuation color?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to change the color of the "{" and "}" that defines an object in my VS Code editor. The code is JavaScript.

I've used the "Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes" to identify the textmate scopes and added them to my settings.json file. However, the color is not changed. I have other changes that are working but this one does not. Anyone have a solution?

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": { 
         "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": ["punctuation.definition.block.js"
                , "meta.objectliteral.js"
                , "meta.array.literal.js"
                , "meta.var.expr.js"
                , "source.js"],
                "settings": {
                    "foreground": "#ac0e0e"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Mark's answer is correct, but what confuses me is why what you tried isn't changing the colour for you. It changes the colour for me. Is your language mode in the JS file set to JavaScript? Does the issue reproduce with extensions disabled?

Comment: I tried Mark's solution but it did not change. My tab and the status bar in the lower right shows JavaScript as the language. The only active extensions are Copilot and GitHub Pull. If I completely remove the tokenColorCustomizations and use the Inspect Editor to view the { on an object it shows "foreground   No theme selector". It's very strange that it works for both of you.

Comment: 1) what theme are you using? 2) Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```json
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [

          {
            "scope": "punctuation.definition.block.js",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#f00"
            }
        }
      ]
    }
```

You frequently do not need the entire scope chain to work.

You had your scopes separated by commas, which makes them individual rules and the foreground color is applied to each independently.  So what you had was overbroad - it did color the `{}` for me but also colored other parts of the object.

If you ever do need to use more of the scope chain just separate the scopes by a space - that way they are considered as one scope modifier.